Creating a Windows console in Unity
I know I can use Debug.Log() in Unity to use the Unity console, but I find it's a bit verbose for my needs and would rather a plain Windows console. I've tried creating a Windows console in a Unity script as:
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Console : MonoBehaviour
{
    Process consoleProcess;

    void Awake()
    {
        consoleProcess = new Process();
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k";
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        consoleProcess.Start();
    }
}

However, even with consoleProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k" the console window opens and closes immediately, how can I fix this? Furthermore, once I have the console opened persistently, what would be the best way to output to it from any script in my Unity project?

the normal answer is to create a developer console inside the game which you can spout your messages to - at the same time, when your built game runs, it creates a log file, where all your debug messages are kept - except i think in webgl, where its output to the console messages of your browser.
